# Dúvida sobre leitura de arquivos texto em C

Tags: c, arquivo, texto

Meu problema é simples, eu criei um seguinte arquivo listando alguns filmes:

[image: Meu arquivo de listas]

O que eu desejo é literalmente ler o que está aí dentro e imprimir no terminal, eu estou ciente da existência de funções de leituras de arquivos(fscanf, fgets...) porém elas não parecem se adequar a minha situação, porque essa função pede pra passar uma string por parâmetro, porém eu não tenho string no meu código, pelo que eu entendi lendo a documentação dessas funções, a string seria dada pelo usuário, porém eu não tenho essa string no meu código, eu quero que essa string seja na verdade todo  o meu texto contido já dentro do arquivo.`#include

## include

int main (void) {

```
FILE *arquivo; 
char texto[760]; // variável "place holder" pra considerar o texto do bloco 
                      de notas
arquivo=fopen("lista.txt","r"); // abertura do arquivo pra leitura

if(arquivo==NULL) {
    printf("ERROR"); 
    exit(1); 
}


fgets(texto,  759, arquivo);  // fgets usado de forma totalmente errada, pois não sabia oq passar no lugar da string

fclose(arquivo); 

printf("%s", arquivo); `
```

Agradeço desde já!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conforme descrito na [documentação](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/), você precisa passar um buffer para ser utilizado durante a leitura:

> **Parameters**
>
> **str**
>
> Pointer to an array of chars where the string read is copied.
>
> **num**
>
> Maximum number of characters to be copied into str (including the terminating null-character).
>
> **stream**
>
> Pointer to a FILE object that identifies an input stream.
>       stdin can be used as argument to read from the standard input.

Dito isso, utilize um buffer da seguinte forma:

```
char buffer[1024];
while(fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), arquivo) != NULL)
    printf("%s", buffer);
}
```

Comment: Muito obrigado! realmente depois de fazer o que você falou consegui imprimir direito a lista!